# Reading text data from a text file into an object containing an array

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I need help creating a class that allows me to read in a text file that contains data on players that will be stored into single variables, and then an array. The variables that need to be store is name, day, month, year, country, previousTeams[] For example, one line in the text file will read Cristiano Ronaldo, 19, 05, 1986, Portugal, Manchester United ; Real Madrid.

My biggest struggle at the moment is trying to understand on how to store the array in the text file, if anyone could get me with this I would be very grateful.

Thank you very much for the answers everyone, how would I go about using the split to extract the data into the array? From the example, I am trying to store Manchester United and Real Madrid into an array using  ";" delimiter to specify the next String to be stored into an array. This is what I have come up with, but is far from completed:

```
    while(input.hasNext()){
        String name = input.next();
        int day = input.nextInt();
        int month = input.nextInt();
        int year = input.nextInt();
        String country = input.next();
        String previousTeams[] = ?;
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: So what code have you completed so far? It would be impossible to help without seeing your attempt.

Comment: You have a number of possible options, you might, for example, simply construct a `String` representing all the data for a single line and then write that to the file.  `StringJoiner` might be useful in that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that data will be there for each field. [i.e data will be separated with ',' and previous teams will be separated with ';' & Single player data is stored in single lines]

First of all you should identify entites in the Problem
I have taken 'Player' as an Entity.

We need to create an Array/List of Player Objects to solve the Problem

This is the data contained by Input file:

Cristiano Ronaldo, 19, 05, 1986, Portugal, Manchester United ; Real Madrid

Rahul Dravid, 19, 05, 1986, India, RCB ; RR ; DD

ABD, 19, 05, 1986, South Africa, DD; RCB

Dhoni, 19, 05, 1986, India, CSK; RPS

R.Jadeja, 19, 05, 1986, India, CSK; GL

Following Code will do the Job I guess :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Reader {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        try{
            String absoluteFilePath = "You Input File Absolute Path";
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(absoluteFilePath)));
            String singleEntry = null;
            Player player;
            // Iterate through the file content line by line
            while((singleEntry = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null) {

                // process each line and convert it into a object of player
                // that will be easier to handle going forward
                player = getPlayer(singleEntry);

                // Do anything you want to do with Player
                // I have just printed it out
                System.out.println(getPlayer(singleEntry));
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static Player getPlayer(String input) {
        Player player = new Player();

        // Tokenizer to break the line into tokens i.e information (here name, day etc)
        StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(input);

        player.setName(stringTokenizer.nextToken(",").trim()); // trim() Just to remove spaces 

        player.setDay(Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextToken(",").trim())); // trim() Just to remove spaces

        player.setMonth(Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextToken(",").trim())); // trim() Just to remove spaces

        player.setYear(Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextToken(",").trim())); // trim() Just to remove spaces

        player.setCountry(stringTokenizer.nextToken(",").trim()); // trim() Just to remove spaces

        player.setPreviousTeams(stringTokenizer.nextToken(",").trim().split("[;]")); // trim() Just to remove spaces

        return player;
    }
}



import java.util.Arrays;

public class Player {
    private String name;
    private int day;
    private int month;
    private int year;
    private String country;
    private String[] previousTeams;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }
    public void setDay(int day) {
        this.day = day;
    }
    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }
    public void setMonth(int month) {
        this.month = month;
    }
    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    public String[] getPreviousTeams() {
        return previousTeams;
    }
    public void setPreviousTeams(String[] previousTeams) {
        this.previousTeams = previousTeams;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Player [name=" + name + ", day=" + day + ", month=" + month + ", year=" + year + ", country=" + country
                + ", previousTeams=" + Arrays.toString(previousTeams) + "]";
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recently extracted the data from a csv file and put the contents into a class after reading it. See below, you can adjust this to suit for a txt file.

```
private ArrayList<Solar> sols;


sols = new ArrayList();
BufferedReader crunchifyBuffer = null;
final String DELIMITER = ",";


    try {
        crunchifyBuffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Documents\\Molar Forecasts\\fs-rad.20170421.21.csv"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
                String line = null;
    try {
        line = crunchifyBuffer.readLine(); // Read first line
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
if (line != null) { try {
    // Check it's not null
    //   line = crunchifyBuffer.readLine(); // Read second line
    while ((line = crunchifyBuffer.readLine()) != null)
    {
        //Get all tokens available in line
        String[] tokens = line.split(DELIMITER);
        Solar sol = new Solar(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2], Double.parseDouble(tokens[3]));

        sols.add(sol);

    }   } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}}
```

My class is as follows:

```
class Solar {
    private String station;
    private String period;
    private String forecasttime;
    private Double forecast;


    public String details(){
      return period;
   }

   public Double details1() {
      return forecast;
   }



    public Solar(String station, String period, String forecasttime,Double forecast) {
        this.station = station;
        this.period = period;
        this.forecasttime = forecasttime;
        this.forecast = forecast;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return station;
    }

    public void setName(String station) {
        this.station = station;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return period;
    }

    public void setPrice(String period) {
        this.period = period;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return forecasttime;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String forecasttime) {
        this.forecasttime = forecasttime;
    }

     public Double getAuthor1() {
        return forecast;
    }

    public void setAuthor1(Double forecast) {
        this.forecast = forecast;
    }



}
```

Comment: Based on this: `Cristiano Ronaldo, 19, 05, 1986, Portugal, Manchester United ; Real Madrid` the OP is using two different delimiters ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` to extract the information from the line, here is an example, from text to array :

```
String str = "Cristiano Ronaldo, 19, 05, 1986, Portugal, Manchester United ; Real Madrid";
String[] spl = str.split("[,;]");
```

**Output**

```
Cristiano Ronaldo,  
19,  
05,  
1986,  
Portugal,  
Manchester United ,  
Real Madrid
```